# How to efficiently count at least 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table that stores data from many interfaces to a equip, if all the interfaces work well, millons of rows are received in 1 day, the table is a view so there are no index keys.

```
Interface   Equip   Readtime
a           HA55    01/01/2021 00:02
b           HA56    01/01/2021 00:05
c           HA55    01/01/2021 00:41
a           HA56    01/02/2021 01:23
a           HA57    01/02/2021 04:00
b           HA54    01/01/2021 05:12
```

I want to scan daily, and from the previous day if all the equips received at least data from 1 interface, but the table has so many rows that even a select * where day=yesterday takes long to execute.

So is there an efficient way to count only if exist one interface from one equip and then stop and search for other interface?

Comment: a SELECT DISTINCT Equip should be efficient but it will depend on the indexes you have (the view will still use the indexes of the tables used in the view).  But it's impossible to guess for us what is behind the view.

Comment: _have a very large table_ and _table is a view_ contradict each other. Which is it? Rather than guess, post DDL for the tables involved (and view if applicable).

Comment: So what is the exact table definition, and what are the indexes (if any)?

Comment: I think you need an index on the table if you want efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

An over-the-top example could be...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT *
                FROM yourTable
               WHERE <somecondition>
            )
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: i would do TOP 1 *... so it will not return multiple rows (in case), if exists - its exists

Comment: @PowerMouse There is no reason to use "TOP" within an exists clause. The DB engine will stop looking as soon as it finds the first row.